# What are the advantages of splitting a string to initiliase a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, design-patterns, initialization

This pattern is quite common; I've seen it in a few places including the jQuery source code:

```
var arr = "word1 word2 word3".split(" ");
```

as an alternative to the 'normal' methods of array initiliasation:

```
var arr1 = [ "word1", "word2", "word3" ];

var arr2 = new Array( "word1", "word2", "word3" );
```

What are the benefits of the string-splitting approach?

Comment: Apologies if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find it in any of the 'related answers'. It's also a difficult thing to find via google - well, it was for *me* ...

Comment: Just because jQuery uses it doesn't mean that it is the most awesome way of doing it. It is still contributed to by individual people and all code isn't exactly code reviewed by elite experts before commit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From John Resig (creator of jQuery):](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-so-much-use-of-split-in-jq-instead-of-just-an-array)

> "the only benefit i see is character
>   count in the source and one string
>   rather than numerous." Bingo!
>
> Now that I think about, I think
>   Closure may optimize this point (don't
>   think YUIMin did). I can check in to
>   it again.

Also, the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) recommends avoiding `new Array()` because "Array constructors are error-prone due to their arguments." The guide has a more thorough explanation.

Comment: Excellent - thanks for tracking down reference

Answer (score 3):

The first is shorter. In JS libs these days that's an issue. It's also easier to write: less `,` and `'`. It's also harder to mistype.

Comment: Good point(s). However, isn't `[ ... ]` faster? I would have thought that was a factor in lib design too. Granted, not much, but in the example I'm looking at, there's only a saving of 4 bytes space-wise.

Comment: If it's only a few elements, the win is small (or anti). In JS compressors, the list is usually 50+ elements. The speed gained is in downloading, not in evalling the script to make it useful (don't ask me why, I don't get that either). I think many people think if your LS lib is small, it's good. (BTW I think you're right: `[...]` is faster)

Comment: Also, there might be more... Maybe it's actually faster (??) or less error prone (??).